# Spring: @RequestScope - annotated method does not get called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, javabeans

In the application I would like to create a request-scoped bean (annotated with `@RequestScope`) that would represent a user of the application (for authentication OAuth2 is used with the company's own authentication provider based off keycloak; the problem is that the `Principal` doesn't contain extra information about the permissions this particular user has and they have to be retrieved from another service, which is why I want to have this request-scoped bean that would retrieve fresh permissions on each request).

```
public class MyApplicationUser {
  private final String name;
  private final List<Permission> permissions;

  /* all-arg constructor, getters */
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class UserConfiguration {
  private final PermissionService permissionService;

  /* constructor, etc */
  @Bean
  @RequestScope
  public MyApplicationUser currentUser(@CurrentSecurityContext(expression = "authentication") OAuth2AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) {
    /* call permissionService, map the result and the token details data to MyApplicationUser instance and return it*/
  }
}
```

Although on each request a new instance of `MyApplicationUser` is created, it is not created by calling the `currentUser` method (it **never** gets called), but rather it seems that spring uses the provided constructor and supplies nulls as parameters, which is not what I want. **How do I fix that?**

P.S. the main class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`